# wrong permissions on windows files and folders (contained in a docker container)

Tags: docker, powershell, prestashop, file-permissions

I just installed Prestashop image with docker, but when I want to access the admin URL (of type http://localhost:8080/adminxxxxx), I get a **403 error**, "You don't have permission to access this resource.".

I know that on linux files should be with **755** permissions and folders with **644** permissions.

But I don't know how to settle theses permissions in Windows, any help ?

Thank you !

p.s: the files of the Prestashop images can be found here on Windows: \wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\overlay2\e0bab9108e266a7c48cf73b1f7545a9d6b9ed914b1d47edf898bb1a1ed71cfff\diff\var\www    which apparently belongs to the *network* folder.

Comment: It would probably easier for the community to help if you provide more details on how you installed and ran the image. The error seems to be related to not being able to access the site running in the container and nothing to do with the location of the image in the host. Check the instructions on docker hub on how to run the image and see if that helps https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually started the CLI and executed the appropriate commands (chmod), and it's working. So I guess the folder permissions concerned were for the virtual folders.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a windows container, probably IIS is being used to host the web application. Try to connect to the container using IIS, and then look at the security for the files. Microsoft has many folders and the default permissions and user rights for IIS 7.0 and later which should be useful to you, at the following webpage,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/default-permissions-user-rights